# dpfloat isn't obeying my leftfullpage and fullpage directives

Tags: floats, dpfloat

I'm using dpfloat for figures which are large (or have large captions) so I can have the caption on the left-hand side and the illustration on the right.

It works until about page 50 of my dissertation, then three figures in a row have the caption starting on the right-hand side and the illustration starting on the very next left-hand side (so, they're offset by +1 pages).

I imagine I must be doing something incredibly stupid to cause it to behave this way, but cannot for the life of me figure out what it is.

Included below is the figure code.

```
%== Figure 2 ==
\begin{figure}[p]% should be left side, but prints on p. 52
  \begin{leftfullpage}
  {\caption[The matrix formalism for calculating phenolog overlaps]{\textbf{The matrix formalism for calculating phenolog overlaps} is
    especially important when predicting between species where large
    gene family expansions have occurred since
    species divergence, such as between \textit{Arabidopsis} and
    humans. The example uses human and mouse to illustrate the orthogroup-based matrix formalism.
    (\textbf{a}) Phenotype associations (colors) are plotted as graphs for
    genes from human (left nodes, subscripted $h$) and mouse (right
    nodes, subscripted $m$), showing genes' orthology relationships (edges radiating from
    orthogroups --- middle nodes, labeled $O$). The orthologies (from INPARANOID), are used
    to ``translate'' phenotype associations
    between species (in the case of the gene-based matrix
    framework in panels (\textbf{b, c})) or into an intermediate collection of
    orthogroup--phenotype associations (for the orthogroup-based
    matrix framework in (\textbf{d})). Orthogroup vertices
    (e.g., $O_A$) connect human and mouse orthologs (such as
    $A_h$, $A'_h$, and $A''_h$, which are paralogs of one another
    relative to the human--mouse divergence, with $A_m$ and $A'_m$. Red vertices within a species are genes
    associated with the phenotype of interest ($\phi_h$ for human and
    $\phi_m$ for the mouse phenotype); orthogroup colors reflect the species data.
    These associations can alternately be captured by representing
    the graphs as matrices (\textbf{b--d}), with bullets indicating an
    association between a given genetic element and a
    phenotype. Specifically, (\textbf{b}) and (\textbf{c}) represent the gene-based
    formalism, and (\textbf{d}) illustrates the orthogroup-based
    formalism. Human and mouse phenotype columns are indicated by
    $\phi_h$ and $\phi_m$, respectively.}\label{fig2}}
  \end{leftfullpage}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]% right side, but instead prints on p. 53.
  \begin{fullpage}
    {\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{knn-figs/final_f2.pdf}}
  \end{fullpage}
\end{figure}
```

Any ideas? I'm not even really sure what extra information to provide.

Comment: Aren't the even pages the left-hand pages?  So printing the first on page 52 should be fine.

Comment: Well, if that's true, then it's doing half right and half wrong. Regardless, when I print it, sometimes the caption and figure span a visible page, and sometimes they're on different sides of the same leaf.

Comment: I think you need to provide with more sample code.  Do have other types of figures? Are you setting page numbers explicitly at some point? ...

Comment: Yes. Most of my figures are not double-page --- just regular figures. It's a pretty standard dissertation template: http://www.utexas.edu/ogs/etd/LaTeX/UT+Dissertation.packages/utdiss2-05.tgz I did add some extra packages, but I don't think any of them should change the page numbering. I am using xelatex instead of latex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the linked template does not set the `twoside` option.  Without that option `dpfloat` has no preference for what a `leftfullpage` is.  Just adding `twoside` as an option to `report` will fix the problem.

For example, you can try the following cut down version of the template, with and without the `twoside` option to the document class.  With `twoside` the first figure appears on pages 2 and 3, the second on 6 and 7; without `twoside` the first is still in the same place but the second is on 5 and 6.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{utdiss2} %Example works also with this package commented out
\usepackage{dpfloat}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amscd} 
\usepackage{eucal}      
\usepackage{verbatim}       
\usepackage{makeidx}        
%\usepackage{psfig}             % Obselete
\usepackage{graphicx}           % Instead of epsfig
\usepackage{cite}           % Instead of obselete citesort 

\usepackage{lipsum} % For sample text in this example

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[p]
  \begin{leftfullpage}
  {\caption[Left page caption]{Long text.  Long text.  Long text.
  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long
  text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.
  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long
  text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.
  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long
  text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.
  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long
  text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.
  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long
  text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.
  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long
  text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.
  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long
  text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.
  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  Long text.  }\label{fig2}} 
  \end{leftfullpage}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
  \begin{fullpage}
    {\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
  \end{fullpage}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2-4]

\begin{figure}[p]
  \begin{leftfullpage}
  {\caption{Left page caption.}\label{fig2}}
  \end{leftfullpage}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
  \begin{fullpage}
    {\includegraphics[width=1.0\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
  \end{fullpage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

A couple of the packages in the template are obselete, I have added comments in the above suggesting replacements.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so so much! I sure wish the `twoside` thing was also in the dpfloat instructions. Where did you find it?

Comment: Glad it helped.  I looked in the source code `dpfloat.sty`, which makes a test for the twoside option before deciding what to do.